# How have an undefined date input and get them with symfony?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I have a form with Symfony. In the form I have a datetime input. The user have to decide how many date input he need. He can add 4 datetime or 3 or anything they want...

How can I do that with Symfony?

I can add a select with number with 1 to 20 for example, and I can append these inputs via jQuery, but then how to get them via my form builder with symfony?

Comment: Did you hear about [CollectionType Field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)?

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is.

Comment: I'd even say, use [this documentation page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) to help you.